# Grant create user permission Snowflake

Tags: permissions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, roles, system-administration, createuser

Its a newbie question but still I am trying to `grant create user` permission to `sysadmin` role from the `accountAdmin` role so that I can create users in the sysadmin role.

The statement I am trying to execute is:

```
grant create user to role sysadmin;
```

**Error**

```
SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 18 unexpected 'to'.
```

What's the exact statement to achieve this?
I tried googling but haven't found any exact query statement in a long time, so posting it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grant create user on account to role role_name ;

Please note that this statement has to be submitted as an ACCOUNTADMIN

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html

You could also choose to use the WITH GRANT OPTION which allows the grantee to regrant the role to other users.

Grant create user on account to role role_name WITH GRANT OPTION;